# Trouble with basic todo app angular js

Tags: angularjs, scoping

I am a newbie to this framework struggling to understand scope .

I followed the basic steps for creating a todo app given in the yeoman website.

**Here is my code :**

**Index.Html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="mytodoApp">
    <div class="container" ng-include="'views/main.html'" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
    <script>
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Main.Html**

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>My todos</h2>

    <!-- Todos input -->
    <form role="form" ng-submit="addTodo()">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" ng-model="todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p></p>

    <!-- Todos list -->
    <div ui-sortable ng-model="todos">
        <p class="input-group" ng-repeat="todo in todos" style="padding: 5px 10px; cursor: move;">
            <input type="text" ng-model="todo" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeTodo($index)" aria-label="Remove">X</button>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Main.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('mytodoApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.todos = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
      $scope.addTodo = function () {
          $scope.todos.push($scope.todo);
          $scope.todo = '';
      };
      $scope.removeTodo = function (index) {
          $scope.todos.splice(index, 1);
      };
  });
```

**App.JS**

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('mytodoApp', []);
```

**When i click on add  button, the $scope.todo is undefined and its adding an item showing empty text box.**

The delete functionality is working absolutely fine.

I guess the problem is with the scoping . Can any one care to guide me with regards to this ?

Updated :

Please find below screen

[image]
**I am not getting any error rather the output is wrong.**

This is what heppening when trying to add a new item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) executes at priority level 500, while [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) executes at priority level 400.

So first, ngController will create a scope, then ngInclude. That is to say, in your included HTML file, every time you want to access a variable scoped in your controller, you'll need to prefix with `$parent`, e.g. `ng-submit="$parent.addTodo()"`.

The other solution (better IMHO) is to remove the ngController attribute from the div which has the ngInclude, and to put it in on the surrounding div within your HTML file:

**Index.html:**

```
<div class="container" ng-include="'views/main.html'"></div>
```

**Main.html:**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

hey you are mixing scopes here first you have a todo for a new item and another "the same" todo for each element in the ng-repeat and also you don't need to re-define ng-model inside of the repeater just use the curly brackets notation for referencing to the scope.

change the name ng-repeat like:

```
<div>
        <p class="input-group" ng-repeat="element in todos" style="padding: 5px 10px; cursor: move;">
            <span>{{element}}</span>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeTodo($index)" aria-label="Remove">X</button>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

**EDIT:**

this is a working version of what you got

http://plnkr.co/edit/CrNrryNTiFFqzhWxaM7P

plnker code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <h2>My todos</h2>

    <!-- Todos input -->
    <form role="form" ng-submit="addTodo()">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" ng-model="todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p></p>

    <!-- Todos list -->
    <div ui-sortable ng-model="todos">
        <p class="input-group" ng-repeat="element in todos" style="padding: 5px 10px; cursor: move;">
            {{element}}
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeTodo($index)" aria-label="Remove">X</button>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.todos = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
      $scope.addTodo = function () {
          $scope.todos.push($scope.todo);
          $scope.todo = '';
      };
      $scope.removeTodo = function (index) {
          $scope.todos.splice(index, 1);
      };
});
```

Comment: Thank you . Can you please see my index.html code where i am using ng-include to include main.html in index.html. Is that the correct way , or is it beacause of which the problem is occuring. Rest of code is same as your code

Comment: Open another question and tag me on that

Comment: Is ng-incude creating a new child scope ?

Comment: Here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655909/does-ng-incude-a-new-scope

Comment: Can you answer to that question on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: just in case, can you remove you google analytics code, and see what happens/

Comment: still the output is same

Comment: that's weird everything seems fine to me, look at my code, compare it to you and take your own conclusions

Comment: I'd suggest you to use yeoman, it creates all the boilerplate code for you, and the structure, take a pick make a try you'll learn pretty quick from there.

Comment: try another generator I'd suggest cg-angular https://github.com/cgross/generator-cg-angular, maybe it's a library your code is fine!

Comment: Plunker is a scope for index.html and when ng-incude is used , it creates a new child scope , can we use the same scope in the controller

Comment: but anyway you should be able to reach the scope in the controller whatever you use ng-include or not

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63942/discussion-on-answer-by-jack-the-ripper-trouble-with-basic-todo-app-angular-js).