# Does ng-incude creates a new child scope?

Tags: angularjs

**Does ng-include creates a new child scope ?**

```
<html>
<body ng-app="mytodoApp">
<div class="container" ng-include="'views/main.html'" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: You should make some efforts and read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude:

> This directive creates new scope.

Comment: How to get the child scope ?

Comment: @SaiAvinash From where?

Comment: @sp00m..can you please have a look at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654059/trouble-with-basic-todo-app-angular-js/26654181?noredirect=1#comment41914735_26654181